# Does JPQL have single- and/or multi-line comments?

Tags: java, orm, jpql

Question says it all... If they exist, which characters are used?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. At least not according to the [full language specification](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnbuf.html).